# Paste in text field and bind to form fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to have an input box where the client can paste information. Then the information pasted in the box automatically will get binded / inputed in the correct form field so the client can review the content and possibly edit it  before sending the form. How do I take the pasted content and bind it to the input fields?

The content to be pasted in the input box will always have this format:

**Serial number:    Equipment:  Liable: E-mail liable:  Next service:   Bought:**

**1234567890    Mac computer    Test Testson    test.testson@example.com    2020-05-17  2019-05-17**

So the first row with the category and the second row with the actual content to be filled in the input fields of the form. The content from "textarea" to be binded to the correct input fields.

```
<h2>Service form</h2>

<textarea rows = "2" cols = "60" name = "import field">
Paste content here
     </textarea><br>

<form action="/action_page.php">

  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>

  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>

    Serial number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>

    Equipment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>  

  Next service:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>

    Bought:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: This will not be possible  because the value row can not be separated. I mean how can we know what "Mac computer Test Testson" be split to

Comment: @Andam The fields can be seperated with tab or semicolon. Would that be possible?

Comment: Yes, semicolon would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what we are doing here is, we remove the new line character `\n` from the text area value. Then we split the string into field names and values by the last occurrence of `:` after that we split the field and value string into array by character `:` and `;` finally we have given the the form input field an `id` same as the text only without `space` and `-` and we assign the value to the field

```js
function arrange(){
  var data = document.getElementById("Data").value.replace("\n", "");

  var fieldPart = data.substr(0, data.lastIndexOf(":") +1).split(":");
  var valuePart = data.substr(data.lastIndexOf(":") +1, data.length).split(";");

  fieldPart.pop();
  valuePart.pop();

  for(var i = 0; i < fieldPart.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(fieldPart[i].replace(/ /g, "").replace(/-/g, "")).value = valuePart[i].trim();
  }
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 700px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Service form</h2>

<textarea id="Data" rows = "2" cols = "60" name = "import field" palceholder="Paste content here">

</textarea><br>
<button onclick="arrange()">Arrange</button>
<form action="/action_page.php">

  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="Liable">
  <br>

  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="Emailliable">
  <br>

    Serial number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="Serialnumber">
  <br>

    Equipment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="Equipment">
  <br>  

  Next service:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="Nextservice">
  <br>

    Bought:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="Bought">
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. But if the content that is pasted in the input box varies? The categories will still be the same but for example the serial number will vary. In this snippet the values in the form fields don't change depending on what I type in.

Comment: @SimonSidmalm do you mean the value inside the textarea? Anyway I have changed the code. Try it now.

Comment: Yes. But now it doesn't seem to work. When i click "Arrange" it doesn't bind the content in the textarea to the input fields.

Comment: @SimonSidmalm you are correct I fixed it. by the way you have add the semicolon to the values as we mention the comments like this. 
Serial number: Equipment: Liable: E-mail liable: Next service: Bought:

1234567890; Mac computer; Test Testson; test.testson@example.com; 2020-05-17; 2019-05-17;